# Output fields manually in Woocommerce email templates

Tags: templates, woocommerce-offtopic, email

I want to build a custom email template for the emails that are sent to customers when an order is placed. I will refer to `customer-processing-order.php` file. In it, there are two actions that display order details `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );` and customer details `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );`.

Digging deeper I see that in `email-customer-details.php` there is a foreach loop that outputs the contents of this function `echo wp_kses_post( $field['value']`. In `email-addresses.php` the address is displayed using this function `<?php echo $order->get_formatted_billing_address(); ?>`.

What I would like to do is to build an email template with each field parsed manually. How can I output the content of the functions above on a field by field basis? I want to mix fields in between them do display something like

```
Customer Name
Customer Address
Customer Phone
Custom checkout fields that I built
Customer shipping address
```

Is there a way to display each field from Customer Details and Billing Address manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to manually construct a new Billing address format by creating a copy of the WooCommerce email address template in `/your-theme-driectory/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php` by replacing the original echo `$order->get_formatted_billing_address();` with for example:

```
$output  = '<strong>Customer Name: </strong>'.get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_first_name', true).'<br>';
$output .= '<strong>Customer Last Name: </strong>'.get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_last_name', true).'<br>';
$output .= '<strong>Company Name: </strong>'.get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_company', true).'<br>';
$output .= '<strong>Country: </strong>'.WC()->countries->countries[get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_country', true)].'<br>';
echo $output;
```